# Why my header of the bibliography part (thesis) is the continuation of the last chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, page-numbering

Why my header of the bibliography part (thesis) is the continuation of the last chapter? please how is it solved? the below is the sequence of the codes used in Latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage[font={Large}]{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.2in, left=2.0 cm,right=2.0 cm,top=2 cm, bottom=2.5 cm ,footskip=.25in ]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{lineno}
\begin{document}
\input{FrontPage}
\newpage
\cleardoublepage% \clearpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of contents}
% List of Figures %
\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of figures}
% List of Tables %
\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of tables}
\newpage
\input{acro_list}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of abbreviation}
\clearpage% \clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapter1}
\input{Chapter2}
\input{Chapter3}
\input{Chapter4}
\input{Chapter5}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{References}}
\includepdf{KurdishTitle}
\includepdf{KurdishAbstract}
\includepdf{ArabicTitle}
\includepdf{ArabicAbstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer without knowing the document class and the packages used...

Comment: Off-topic: if your bibliography is more than one page, the toc will probably show the wrong page number

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example which we can actually compile to reproduce the issue. Remember that we don't have all your included files.

Comment: Without a usable document it's extremely difficult to see. Too many files are included that we don't have. Moreover, I don't see any code for setting up the headers.

Comment: Thank you, i will create the file from scratch